# What is the difference between the angle of incidence, refraction and deflection?

Tags: visible-light

If a ray of light is passed through a piece of rectangular acrylic as shown in image below, how can i predict the deflection of the ray? Should i look at the angles angle of incidence, refraction or deflection? What is the difference between them if any?

[image]

Comment: Look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research.

Comment: Hi Arthur. Starting with the known angle of incidence use Snell's law to calculate the angle of the light inside the block. Then use the width of the block to calculate where the light hits the far side of the block. Finally use Snell's law again to calculate the angle the light leaves the block.